# kill while loop with keystroke in vbs

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

Currently this script is running for 5 minutes, but I need to stop this by keystroke.

```
Option Explicit
Dim Excel, x, y, x1, y1, eTime
Set Excel = WScript.CreateObject("Excel.Application")
eTime = DateAdd("n", 2, Now)
x = "111"
y = "222"
x1 = "222"
y1 = "111"
Do While Now < eTime
    Excel.ExecuteExcel4Macro ( _
        "CALL(""user32"",""SetCursorPos"",""JJJ""," & x & "," & y & ")")
    WScript.Sleep (1000)
    Excel.ExecuteExcel4Macro ( _
        "CALL(""user32"",""SetCursorPos"",""JJJ""," & x1 & "," & y1 & ")")
  WScript.Sleep (1000)
Loop
WScript.Echo "Program Ended"
```

I have tried below code but it's not working, am I doing wrong?

```
Option Explicit
Dim Excel, x, y, x1, y1, eTime
Set Excel = WScript.CreateObject("Excel.Application")
eTime = DateAdd("n", 2, Now)
x = "111"
y = "222"
x1 = "222"
y1 = "111"

Sub Form_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    Do While Not KeyAscii = 27
        Excel.ExecuteExcel4Macro ( _
            "CALL(""user32"",""SetCursorPos"",""JJJ""," & x & "," & y & ")")
        WScript.Sleep (1000)
        Excel.ExecuteExcel4Macro ( _
            "CALL(""user32"",""SetCursorPos"",""JJJ""," & x1 & "," & y1 & ")")
        WScript.Sleep (1000)
    Loop
    WScript.Echo "Program Ended"
```

Comment: Plain VBScript can't do what you want, but VBA can ([related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23725598/1630171)).

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question [How to stop a loop when pressing "OK" on a message box with VBS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44146772/how-to-stop-a-loop-when-pressing-ok-on-a-message-box-with-vbs/44376414#44376414)

Maybe you can adapt this to your code.
It's a way to loop until something appen without freezing.

One thing: you need to use a HTA windows linked to a vbs file.

Comment: updated script but giving error variable undefined "Wscript"